# Can't get stdin to read into array on linux - Java

Tags: java, linux

So I'm using Java on a Linux machine and I currently am trying to read from stdin so that when I run "java Simulation more ~test/locationOfInput/test" it takes a stream of numbers and calculates values and prints them. However, my code is locking up when trying to read in the values and I have a check for empty files so I know it's at least receiving the file. I currently have this code to read the stdin into an array

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = input.nextInt();
        values.add(i);
    }
```

The loop seems to be running infinitely and I'm not sure why. Am I misunderstanding how to read in from STDIN?

Comment: You have nothing which stops your `while` loop...

Comment: What happens if you type 'please stop I can't take this anymore' on the input line after the last integer you wanted to add? btw kudos for using a `ArrayList`!

Comment: @Al1 not having an integer on the line will stop the loop.

Comment: @M.leRutte my bad, I forgot that. Thanks for highlight it. And agreed for the `ArrayList`

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to debug your code. You can add `System.out.println()` calls to your code to see what it is doing or use a source-level debugger in an IDE.

Comment: p.s. Does the command you are actually typing to run the program contain a `|`? You missed it in your example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `cat ~test/locationOfInput/test | java Simulation` to redirect the output properly.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! Is there any way for me to run the equivalent of this but in a way where it could be typed as something like ./Simulation cat ~test/locationOfInput/test

Comment: @mewi Why? You can use `java Simulation < ~test/locationOfInput/test` I think, but you're probably best off implementing accepting command line arguments as jrtapsell suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Pipe the input into the program as @daniu suggested
2. Take the file path as an argument and read from the file with the given path

You could implement both in 1 program, so if it has an argument it reads from that file, otherwise it would read from piped input.